# How to set up “xypic.js” on mathjax v3 through CDN

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I want to use xypic.js on mathjax version 3 through CDN.

I have been using it on mathjax version 2.7.5 through CDN. and there, the setting in header is this:

```
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Ajax.config.path["Contrib"] = "//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/contrib";
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        TeX: {  extensions: ["color.js","AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","[Contrib]/xyjax/xypic.js"] },
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"]] }
    });
  </script>
```

but I dont know how to convert these setting into that of version 3.
I used this cite: https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/convert-configuration/convert-configuration.html but it didn't go well because this cite don't refer to how to deal with "MathJax.Ajax.config.path".

I wish a certain sincere person would answer my question.

Comment: It's not possible. xyjax would have to be updated / rewritten to work with MathJax v3.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger  do you have any avidence to say so?

Comment: MathJax v3 is a complete rewrite with a completely different set of APIs - just compare http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/advanced/extension-writing.html#extension-to-define-tex-macros and http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v3.1-latest/web/webpack.html#a-custom-extension. The output mechanisms have changed significantly - the HTML-CSS output was dropped, the CommonHTML output works very differently and the SVG output has changed as well. Since xyjax extends both input and output drastically, I would expect a lot of work. It doesn't help that xyjax's last significant commit is 7 years old.

Comment: thanks. i understood

Comment: XyJax has seen an update, in order to be compatible with MathJax v3. I have not tested it yet.

Comment: @Pieter thanks for good news